# 'Con not a connection' Error in R program

Tags: r

I am trying to use readLines in R but I am getting below error

```
orders1<-readLines(orders,2)
# Error in readLines(orders, 2) : 'con' is not a connection
```

### Code :

```
orders<-read.csv("~/orders.csv")

orders 

orders1<-readLines(orders,2)

orders1
```

### Data:

```
id,item,quantity_ordered,item_cost
1,playboy roll,1,12
1,rockstar roll,1,10
1,spider roll,1,8
1,keystone roll,1,25
1,salmon sashimi,6,3
1,tuna sashimi,6,2.5
1,edamame,1,6
2,salmon skin roll,1,8
2,playboy roll,1,12
2,unobtanium roll,1,35
2,tuna sashimi,4,2.5
2,yellowtail hand roll,1,7
4,california roll,1,4
4,cucumber roll,1,3.5
5,unagi roll,1,6.5
5,firecracker roll,1,9
5,unobtanium roll,1,35
,chicken teriaki hibachi,1,7.95
,diet coke,1,1.95
```

Comment: `read.csv` should return a data.frame. You can't call `readLines` on a data.frame. What do you want `orders1<-readLines(orders,2)` to do? What's your goal there?

Comment: I was trying to read a csv file and then I am trying to read the first 2 lines. Thanks for the explanation. I cannot read lines from a data frame. So if I were read first 2 lines from a data frame , how would i be able to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm guessing you want this:

```
orders1 <- readLines( file("~/orders.csv") )
```

It's not clear why you want to do your own parsing or substitution, but that should give readLines a valid connection object.

Comment: Hi , I added  a 2 in teh end to read first 2 lines. "orders1 <- readLines( file("~/orders.csv"),2 )" . Is there a way to read last two lines, I am actually in need of that which got me stuck at previous error.

Comment: I don't know a way to limit to the last two lines with readLines but you could use `tail(orders1, 2)` to return the last two lines after the file was read in.